Page feedback score using Facebook API
Page feedback scores provide insight into your customers' post-purchase experiences and can indicate whether or not you're complying with our Unacceptable Business Practices policy.
Reference : https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2326130134241747
How to fetch the page feedback score using Facebook API?
